# conditional column mapping in ssis

Tags: sql, etl, ssis

I am a newbie on SSIS. I have a SOURCE table with columns s.CASH , s.ACC_ID and s.ADDITIONAL_NUM  and a TARGET table with column t.ACCT_NUM in my SSIS package. Here is the mapping logic -

If s.CASH > 0 , map s.ACC_ID to t.ACCT_NUM

else map s.ADDITIONAL_NUM to t.ACCT_NUM.

If s.ADDITIONAL_NUM is empty, then t.ACCT_NUM = null

How can implement it in SSIS?

Comment: The general strategy I would use would be to create two columns in a Derived Column Tasks. Apply your logic there and then map those new columns into their targets. Or, simplify your package and just perform the logic in your extract query (don't select the table as your source) and then your data flow is a straight forward affair

Comment: @billinkc - I did not need 2 derived columns since I want to populate value only in one target column with reference to conditionss on two source columns. Please refer to my answer. Thanks for giving your opinion. Much appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@billinkc - Thanks for your suggestion. I chose to create a single derived column and applied following condition -

(CASH > 0) ? [ACC_ID] : ([ADDITIONAL_NM]=="" ? ( DT_WSTR,255) NULL(DT_WSTR,255) : [ADDITIONAL_NM])